# SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for Fatal error: Call to undefined method

Tags: php, class, methods, loading

I have read many posts regarding this error, but not found any working solution for me.

I have a site and master config file which loads all the class files.

Now i created a sub folder in my site and included the master config from parent folder which loads class files.

But i cannot use any of the class functions from subfolders.

I have tested by adding a die statement on one class files, and script perfectly 'died'. but the issue is i cannot use the functions.

**.com**

```
class
--class.document.php
subsite
--index.php
master.config.php
index.php
```

The problem occurs when using functions inside `subsite/index.php`

```
SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Document::loadHelper() in sitepath\subsite\index.php on line 13
```

**and on line 12 & 13**

```
$Document = Document::getDocument();
$Document->loadHelper('properties');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `include` either master.config.php or class/class.document.php from your subsite/index.php

```
include('../master.config.php');
include('../class/class.document.php');
```